# JDBI Object Query

Tags: java, mysql, jdbi

I've used JDBI before for Java persistence stuff before but it's always been the fluent API not the object API. Trying the Object API now.

I've got a DAO Object that is pretty simple:

```
public interface PersonDAO {

@SqlQuery("insert into person(id,first_name,last_name,position) values(:id,:firstName,:lastName,:position)")
void insertPerson(@Bind("id") Integer id,
                  @Bind("firstName") String firstName,
                  @Bind("lastName") String lastName,
                  @Bind("position") String position);
}
```

Tested the query in mysql, it works fine, but running it in a unit test:

```
@Test 
public void testInsertPerson() {
    PersonDAO personDao = dao.getRegHandle().attach(PersonDAO.class);
    personDao.insertPerson(888888,"Tom", "Ford", "Manager");
}
```

I get an exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method
>   com.hrweb.dao.PersonDAO#insertPerson is annotated as if it should
>   return a value, but the method is void.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like you've got the `SqlQuery` annotation not the `SqlUpdate` annotation on your insert statement. Take a look at examples in the JDBI Docs: [Link](http://jdbi.org/sql_object_overview/)

Change the annotation like this:

```
@SqlUpdate("insert into person(id,first_name,last_name,position) values(:id,:firstName,:lastName,:position)")
```

Should get rid of that exception.